# Getting strange two exceptions on EditorWindow script. Any ideas how to fix it and what make it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using 2018.3.0f2 Personal

The exceptions show up once I'm trying to start the script in the editor by doing in the menu: Window > Manager then it's not even showing the editor window but after I'm trying many times it's working. Can't figure out what is going on.

Maybe I should uninstall old unity versions including the current one and re install this one again ? Maybe it's a bug in the 3.0f2 version ?

The two exceptions:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   UnityEditor.EditorWindow.GetRootElement[TMode] (System.Boolean createIfNull) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorWindow.cs:55)
>   Unity.Experimental.EditorMode.EditorModes.GetRootElement[TMode] (UnityEditor.EditorWindow window) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorMode/EditorModes.cs:455)
>   Unity.Experimental.EditorMode.EditorModes+ModeGenericHelper`1[TMode].GetRoot (UnityEditor.EditorWindow window) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorMode/EditorModes.cs:28)
>   Unity.Experimental.EditorMode.EditorModes.GetRootElement (UnityEditor.EditorWindow window) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorMode/EditorModes.cs:215)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.DeregisterSelectedPane (System.Boolean clearActualView, System.Boolean sendEvents) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:399)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.OnDisable () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:103)

And

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   UnityEditor.DockArea.KillIfEmpty () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:234)
>   UnityEditor.DockArea.RemoveTab (UnityEditor.EditorWindow pane, System.Boolean killIfEmpty, System.Boolean sendEvents) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:222)
>   UnityEditor.DockArea.RemoveTab (UnityEditor.EditorWindow pane) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:193)
>   UnityEditor.EditorWindow.set_position (UnityEngine.Rect value) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorWindow.cs:1030)
>   Manager.CenterWindow () (at Assets/Editor/Manager.cs:81)
>   Manager.ShowEditor () (at Assets/Editor/Manager.cs:25)

The script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public class Manager : EditorWindow
{
    private static Manager editor;
    private static int width = 350;
    private static int height = 300;
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;
    private static List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
    private StreamWriter w;

    [MenuItem("Window/Manager")]
    static void ShowEditor()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<Manager>();
        CenterWindow();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Rename"))
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test\names.txt");
            Rename();
        }
    }

    public void Rename()
    {
        DirSearch();

        if (allFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                int idx = allFiles[i].IndexOf("Assets");
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(allFiles[i]);
                string asset = allFiles[i].Substring(idx);
                AnimationClip orgClip = (AnimationClip)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(
                     asset, typeof(AnimationClip));

                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(allFiles[i]);
                var importer = (ModelImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath(asset);

                RenameAndImport(importer, fileName);
            }

            w.Close();
        }
    }

    private void RenameAndImport(ModelImporter asset, string name)
    {
        ModelImporter modelImporter = asset as ModelImporter;
        ModelImporterClipAnimation[] clipAnimations = modelImporter.defaultClipAnimations;

        for (int i = 0; i < clipAnimations.Length; i++)
        {
            clipAnimations[i].name = "magic_" + name;
            w.WriteLine(clipAnimations[i].name);
        }

        modelImporter.clipAnimations = clipAnimations;
        modelImporter.SaveAndReimport();
    }

    private static void CenterWindow()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<Manager>();
        x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;
        editor.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        editor.maxSize = new Vector2(width, height);
        editor.minSize = editor.maxSize;
    }

    static void DirSearch()
    {
        string info = Application.dataPath + "/Mixamo/Animations/medea_m_arrebola/Magic Pack";
        string[] fileInfo = Directory.GetFiles(info, "*.fbx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in fileInfo)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".fbx"))
                allFiles.Add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Line 81 is:

```
editor.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
```

Line 25 is:

```
CenterWindow();
```

I'm not sure if it's connected to the StreamWriter I started using it just yesterday with this script but I can't see anything in the exceptions about the StreamWriter.

Comment: For the StreamWrite I think it would be better to use it with `using` and than pass on the reference to the submethods you call would be a bit cleaned and safer

Comment: Did you try to call [`editor.Show`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Show.html) before changing the position? You also might try [`GetWindowWithRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindowWithRect.html) in order to set the position right from the start